# hashCode and Equals doesn't work properly in Map keys

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashcode

I have Employee class and want to use this class as a key in HashMap and value of that map will be a string. To achieve this, however, I have overridden the equals and hashcode methods in Employee class itself. I have another class to test that whether Employee class key will work correctly or not. After testing, I found that map is storing duplicate keys. Please find below source code and output:

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    private int empAge;

    Employee(){}

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public int getEmpAge() {
        return empAge;
    }

    public void setEmpAge(int empAge) {
        this.empAge = empAge;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if(!(obj instanceof Employee)) return false;

        Employee e = (Employee)obj;

        return e.empId == this.empId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.empId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Id : "+empId+" Name : "+empName+" Age : "+empAge;
    }
}
```

**TestEmployee.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestEmployee {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Employee, String> empMap = new HashMap<Employee, String>();

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setEmpId(10);
        emp1.setEmpName("A");
        emp1.setEmpAge(20);

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setEmpId(20);
        emp2.setEmpName("B");
        emp2.setEmpAge(21);

        empMap.put(emp1, "1");
        empMap.put(emp2, "2");

        System.out.println(empMap);

        emp1.setEmpId(20);

        System.out.println(" emp1.equals(emp2) : "+emp1.equals(emp2));
        System.out.println(" emp1.hashCode() : "+emp1.hashCode()+" emp2.hashCode() : "+emp2.hashCode());

        System.out.println(empMap);

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
{Id : 20 Name : B Age : 21=2, Id : 10 Name : A Age : 20=1}
 emp1.equals(emp2) : true
 emp1.hashCode() : 20 emp2.hashCode() : 20
{Id : 20 Name : B Age : 21=2, Id : 20 Name : A Age : 20=1}
```

Please let me know how can I use unique Employee in map key - uniqueness will decide based on employee ID.

Comment: HashCode will be calculated only when you are inserting into a map. It will not be calculated each time you change the object value inserted into a map using another reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** update the value that is used for hashcode while the object is in a hashmap. The hashcode will be used to decide where to put the object. If you update it afterwards, this update is not "picked up" by the hashmap so at best you have duplicates, at worst you can't retrieve the value connected to the updated key anymore.

**UPDATE**

Please check the javadoc for more information but high level the HashMap chooses a bucket to put the value in based on the hashcode of the key. If you try to retrieve the value with the key, it will look at the hashcode of the key, determine which bucket it should be in, then check that bucket and retrieve the value.

However if between the put() and the get() the hashcode of the key changes, the hashmap might put it in bucket "A" and try to get it in bucket "B".

Comment: Can you please explain me how data fetched from hashmap in this situation? One more thing, I tried to swap the employee ID and when I try to fetch the data then I am getting null.
emp1.setEmpId(20);
emp2.setEmpId(10);

Comment: Where is that bucket store, in a heap space?

Answer (score 0):

In your equals method instead of  using '==' reference comparison use equals method
as '==' comparison checks for reference equality instead of value comparison.
**Like
return e.empId.equals(this.empId);**

Java Integer class properly overrides equals and it will give you correct result.

Comment: The comparison is not a problem since Ravi is comparing ints.

Comment: I've half a mind of downvoting this answer. The OP is asking something else.